# program for entering name, surname and birth year in the dictionary, but the essence of this is to find errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

so I am writing python program for entering name, surname and birth year in the dictionary, but the essence of this is to find errors. For example: if user write letters in the field for entering birth year then the program should warn about this until the user enters the number between 1890 and 2018. I wrote something, but then I got totally stuck.

```
a = input('Enter name: ')
b = input('Enter surname: ')
c = input('Enter birth year: ')

dict = {}
dict['Name'] = a
dict['Surname'] = b
dict['Birth year'] = c

while 1890 > c < 2018:
    if type(c) == str:
         print('Wrong.')
         c = input('Enter birth year: ')
```

Comment: stuck with what? what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: `b` in most cases, will never be a number.

Comment: I don't know how make it work - if user write letters in the field for entering birth year then the program should warn about this until the user enters the number between 1890 and 2018. I mean everything I try it don't work like it should

Comment: I mean c, I will edit it. It was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing `b` in the while condition, whereas `b` is usually a string given your dictionary's key i.e. 'Surname'. Maybe, you want to compare `c` in the while condition.

Edit : Chapter [Input Validation](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter8/) of Automate the Boring Stuff with Python might help with your case.

Comment: Yes thanks for reminding me, I write 'b' by mistake. I want to compare 'c'. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The [input() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string. You need to convert the year value to an integer to check if it is a valid year.

For convenience, user input validation can be moved into a separate function.

Code example:

```py
def check_year(year, min_year, max_year):
    """
    Checks if the value entered by the user
    is a valid year in the specified range.
    
    The range includes min_year and max_year.
    """
    # this part is optional, but covers the most common mistakes
    if any([
        len(year) != 4,
        not year.isdigit(),
        year.startswith('0')
        ]):
        print('The year {} is not a valid value. The correct format is four digits (YYYY).'.format(year))
        return False

    # this part converts the string to a number for comparison
    try:
        converted_year = int(year)
    except ValueError:
        print('The year {} is not a valid value. The correct format is four digits (YYYY).'.format(year))
        return False
    
    # to not include min_year and max_year use: min_year < converted_year < max_year
    if min_year <= converted_year <= max_year:
        return True
    else:
        print('The year {} is not in the {} to {} range.'.format(converted_year, min_year, max_year))
        return False

    
user_data = dict()

a = input('Enter name: ')
user_data['Name'] = a
    
b = input('Enter surname: ')
user_data['Surname'] = b

c = input('Enter birth year (from 1890 to 2018): ')
# exit the While loop if the function returns True
# otherwise, the user is asked to enter new data
while not check_year(c, 1890, 2018):
    c = input('Enter birth year: ')

# save year value as a string
user_data['Birth year'] = c

print(user_data)
```

See also docs:

[Comparison operations in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

[int function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

SO question:

[Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! Means a lot